# Как назвать папку в которой лежат файлы конфигурации и текстовые файлы?

Tags: resources

Может вопрос совсем идиотский, но хотелось бы нормально наименовать, в текущий момент папка называется Configs, в папке Resources, к Resources нет придирок, но как насчет Configs? Там лежат вот такие файлы, а какое название предложите вы?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете назвать папку Settings)

Comment: @АлексейКлещевников я уже подумал, переименовал в etc, больше подходит.)

Answer (score 1):

Очень хороший вариант для такой папки с таким содержимым - `etc`.